# How to get data from my database using two datepickers. CODEIGNITER

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter, datepicker

I want to select all data from my database between my two datepickers. Kindly help me on how to use BETWEEN AND statements in this situation.
I pick a date from the first datepicker and then the data shows, but when i pick a date on 2nd date picker the data of the date from the 2nd date picker is only shown the first one is gone

i used this query

```
$this->db->where('date_sold >=',$this->input->post('selectdate'));

$this->db->where('date_sold <=',$this->input->post('selectdate2'));
```

but i only get 1 data..

```
<span>Select 1st sem:</span>
                <div id="datetimepicker1" class="input-append date">
                    <input data-format="MM/dd/yyyy" type="text" readonly name="selectDate" id="selectDate"></input>                                 
                    <span class="add-on">
                      <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar">
                      </i>                                                        
                    </span>
                </div>
                <script type="text/javascript">

                 $(function(){ 
                    var date = new Date();
                    date.setDate(date.getDate());

                      $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({                            
                            pickTime: false
                      });

                  });
                </script>   

                <span>Select 2st sem:</span>
                <div id="datetimepicker2" class="input-append date">
                    <input data-format="MM/dd/yyyy" type="text" readonly name="selectDate" id="selectDate2"></input>                                    
                    <span class="add-on">
                      <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar">
                      </i>                                                        
                    </span>
                </div>

                <script type="text/javascript">

                 $(function(){ 
                    var date = new Date();
                    date.setDate(date.getDate());
                      $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({                            
                            pickTime: false
                      });

                  });
                </script>
```

/this is my view

```
    function get_semreportdata(){
    $q = $this->db->select('
             books.title,
             reserved_books.id,
             reserved_books.isbn, 
             reserved_books.price,
             reserved_books.item_sold,
             reserved_books.date_sold,
             reserved_books.total_amount
            ')
        ->from('reserved_books')
        ->join('books','reserved_books.isbn= books.isbn')
        ->where('date_sold >=',$this->input->post('selectdate'))
        ->where('date_sold <=',$this->input->post('selectdate2'));



        $reserved['rows'] = $q->get()->result();
        $this->db->select_sum('total_amount');
        $this->db->where('date_sold',$this->input->post('selectdate'));

        $query = $this->db->get('reserved_books');
        $reserved['total'] = $query->result();

        return $reserved;

}
```

this is my model

Answer (score 1):

Both of your fields are named *selectDate* in your code sample. I think this is why your original query isn't working. Try renaming the second field to *selectdate2*

Answer (score 0):

I'd say something like this:

where 'date_sold' between ".$this->input->post('selectdate')." and ".$this->input->post('selectdate')."

Assuming you have the submitted dates in the right format for your database table.

Comment: $this->db->where('date_sold between',$this->input->post('selectdate')." and ".$this->input->post('selectdate2')); i used this but still the selected date of the 2nd date picker is shown

Answer (score 0):

Try this one  make sure you have appropriate type of `date_sold` like date or datetime and also care for posted inputs they contains the exact date format as `date_sold` column has.I have make three cases one for between and other two contains the single date data. I have used custom string in where by passing third parameter as false

```
    $datef=$this->input->post('selectdate');
    $dates=$this->input->post('selectdate2');
    $q = $this->db->select('
             books.title,
             reserved_books.id,
             reserved_books.isbn, 
             reserved_books.price,
             reserved_books.item_sold,
             reserved_books.date_sold,
             reserved_books.total_amount
            ')
        ->from('reserved_books')
        ->join('books','reserved_books.isbn= books.isbn');

if(!empty($datef) && !empty($dates)){
$this->db->where(" `date_sold` BETWEEN '".$datef."' AND '".$dates."' ", NULL, FALSE); 

}elseif(!empty($datef)){
$this->db->where( " `date_sold` >=.'"$datef."' ", NULL, FALSE);

}elseif(!empty($dates)){

$this->db->where(" `date_sold` <=.'".$dates."' ", NULL, FALSE);
}
```

[**Reference**](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/102635/#517771)

> $this->db->where() accepts an optional third parameter. If you set it
>   to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table
>   names with backticks.

[**Active Record**](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)